# Best way to store license key persistently on i-device

Tags: ios, woocommerce, activation

I have a woocommerce store with a plugin which generates license keys.

The idea is that the user of my app, will enter a license key which will be checked against a server. If it is correct then the app will create a special file/persistent flag some how.

Once activated, the user can reset the device or whatever and the app will simply check to see if this persistent file/flag is there.

My questions are:

1. Is there a library available specifically for this sort of thing?
2. If not, what is the best/standard way of doing this so the file can't be copied to another device to fake an activation?
3. Could I use something untouchable inside the application bundle that isn't a file to do this?

Thanks guys, some guidance or suggestions would be great.

Comment: Is this to unlock functionality in your app?  I am pretty sure that in-app purchase is the only method Apple will permit - Of course your problem of how to record the purchase locally remains - although Apple provides advice on how to verify the transaction against a server

Comment: @Paulw11 not true. As long as the payment is not made inside the app, it's fine to accept payments directly instead of giving Apple 30%. For example, Skype credit is be purchased without using in-app purchase. But you can't enter your credit card number into the Skype iOS app — you have to use a web browser. Same for the Kindle app, and many others.

Comment: @Paulw11 also note that in-app-purchase is not allowed to be used for all purchasing. For example you can't use it for physical goods, like when you order a pizza with the Dominos app. For things where in-app-purchase is not allowed to be used Apple does allow a credit card number to be entered into the app. It's worth reading over the rules if you're not sure how they apply to your specific product.

Comment: Yeah.  I was aware of that (physical goods). Thanks

Comment: Hey guys, to clarify they purchase a license key through the site and then enter it into the device, they can't really use the app until they enter the login key and register. A bit like spotify, amazon, skype etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "standard" way to do it is to have Apple manage the licensing for you via in-app purchasing or subscriptions, they provide a secure implementation for checking if something is paid for, but this may not be an option for you.

If you need to roll it yourself, you need to use assymetric encryption, with a private key on a server that nobody can access (except you) and a public key distributed in the app. You also need the `[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString` value on the device, which is a value unique to that device which cannot be changed by the user (unless they jail break).

The server encrypts some data like `2014-03-23,purchased-three-month-license,<device-identifier-for-vendor>,<long-random-number>` and gives the encrypted data to the device as the license key.

The device has the public key, and uses it to decrypt the license key. Then it checks the result to see if the date is in the last three months, the device identifier matches the device's actual identifier, and verifies that the long random number is there and at least 10 digits or something (it doesn't matter what the random number is, it just needs to be there).

Anybody who jail breaks their device will still be able to bypass your security. There is no way to prevent this. But it will take the user a lot of work, they'll probably just pay instead.

All the libraries you need for the encryption are built in, but they're low level APIs and a bit complicated to use and it's easy to screw it up. I recommend [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) as a high level wrapper around them.

Also note that if the user uninstalls your app, then re-installs it (or sometimes when Xcode installs a new build) the `identifierForVendor` will change to a new value. Apple enforces this to protect user privacy, there's no way around it. You will need to have the server re-generate a new license key based on the new identifier... perhaps by asking the user to enter an email address and password. You can prevent piracy by monitoring how many times a particular email address is used. If they generate license keys 5 times in 30 days, then you could flag them as a pirate.

Whatever license key the "woocommerce store plugin" is generating will not work, because it won't be using `[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString` as part of the license key generation. Without that value, it's going to be trivial for anybody to pirate your software.

There is no such thing as "something untouchable inside the application bundle". The only such thing is the [Secure Enclave](http://images.apple.com/au/ipad/business/docs/iOS_Security_EN_Feb14.pdf) in Apple's hardware. And to protect user privacy app developers are not allowed to use it directly. identifierForVendor is the only option.

In older versions of iOS there were more options, but they were abused by advertising companies tracking Apple's customers, and so one by one Apple has blocked access over the years.

Comment: To add more to this, I can't use the standard apple way because they don't offer enough control. The person has to do a course through our company before they can use the app. Very niche use case, I worked with apple for a while but we couldn't come up with a solution with their existing infrastructure :( - thanks for the answer :)